# Load different JPanel depending of the value in my jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

I have a JFrame that contains a JPanel "painelGeral" with a JComboBox cmbTipo(values=Aluno and Funcionario), I also have 2 other JPanels: painelAluno and painelFuncionario and I want that one of them would be displayed below "painelGeral" depending on the selected item in my JComboBox cmbTipo. 
To be more exactly, if the value selected  of my JComboBox(cmbTipo) is 'Aluno' then painelAluno would be showed under painelGeral, and if the value of my JComboBox(cmbTipo) selected is 'Funcionario', then painelFuncionario would be showed
Here is my code that I've tried to do so far:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MembrosView extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton btnAdicionar, btnCancelar;
    private JLabel lblTipo, lblNome, lblEmail, lblCelular, lblRa, lblCurso,
            lblHabilitado, lblCpf, lblEndereco, lblNumero, lblComplemento;
    private JTextField txtNome, txtEmail, txtCelular, txtRa, txtCpf,
            txtEndereco, txtNumero, txtComplemento;
    private JPanel painelPrincipal, painelBotoes, painelGeral, painelAluno,
            painelFuncionario;
    private String[] tipos = { "Aluno", "Funcionário" };
    private JComboBox cmbTipo, cmbCurso;
    private JCheckBox ccbHabilitado;

    public MembrosView() {
        super("Manutenção de Membros");
        btnAdicionar = new JButton("Adicionar");
        btnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");

        // geral
        lblNome = new JLabel("Nome:");
        lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
        lblCelular = new JLabel("Celular:");
        lblTipo = new JLabel("Tipo:");

        // aluno
        lblRa = new JLabel("RA:");
        lblCurso = new JLabel("Curso:");
        lblHabilitado = new JLabel("Habilitado:");

        // professor
        lblCpf = new JLabel("CPF:");
        lblEndereco = new JLabel("Endereço");
        lblNumero = new JLabel("Número:");
        lblComplemento = new JLabel("Complemento:");

        // geral
        txtNome = new JTextField(20);
        txtEmail = new JTextField(20);
        txtCelular = new JTextField(20);

        // aluno
        txtRa = new JTextField(20);
        cmbTipo = new JComboBox(tipos);
        ccbHabilitado = new JCheckBox();
        cmbCurso = new JComboBox();
        // habilitado é checkbox

        // professor
        txtCpf = new JTextField(20);
        txtEndereco = new JTextField(20);
        txtNumero = new JTextField(20);
        txtComplemento = new JTextField(20);

        // botoes
        btnAdicionar.addActionListener(this);
        btnCancelar.addActionListener(this);
        cmbTipo.addActionListener(this);

        painelPrincipal = new JPanel();
        painelAluno = new JPanel();
        painelFuncionario = new JPanel();
        painelBotoes = new JPanel();
        painelGeral = new JPanel();

        painelGeral.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        painelAluno.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        painelPrincipal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        painelBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        painelGeral.add(lblTipo);
        painelGeral.add(cmbTipo);
        painelGeral.add(lblNome);
        painelGeral.add(txtNome);
        painelGeral.add(lblEmail);
        painelGeral.add(txtEmail);
        painelGeral.add(lblCelular);
        painelGeral.add(txtCelular);

        painelAluno.add(lblRa);
        painelAluno.add(txtRa);
        painelAluno.add(lblCurso);
        painelAluno.add(cmbCurso);
        painelAluno.add(lblHabilitado);
        painelAluno.add(ccbHabilitado);

        painelFuncionario.add(lblCpf);
        painelFuncionario.add(txtCpf);
        painelFuncionario.add(lblEndereco);
        painelFuncionario.add(txtEndereco);
        painelFuncionario.add(lblNumero);
        painelFuncionario.add(txtNumero);
        painelFuncionario.add(lblComplemento);
        painelFuncionario.add(txtComplemento);

        painelAluno.setVisible(true);
        painelFuncionario.setVisible(true);

        painelPrincipal.add(painelGeral, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.setContentPane(painelPrincipal);
        this.setSize(400, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MembrosView mv = new MembrosView();

    }

    // se o tipo funcionario for ativado, mostra o painelFuncionario logo abaixo
    // do painel Geral
    // o mesmo pra aluno
    // tentativas que eu fiz mas não deram certo
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cmbTipo.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            painelPrincipal.setSize(400, 600);

            painelPrincipal.repaint();
            painelAluno.repaint();
            painelPrincipal.add(painelAluno, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        cmbTipo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    // int i = (int)
                    // e.getItemSelectable().getSelectedObjects()[0];
                    int i = cmbTipo.getSelectedIndex();
                    if (i == 1) {
                        painelPrincipal.setSize(400, 600);
                        painelPrincipal.add(painelAluno, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        painelPrincipal.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You really should make an effort and at least translate your OP to english with Google, you will raise your chance to get an answer by at least 90%. - Deberías hacer un esfuerzo y por lo menos traducir tu mensaje al inglés con Google, aumentarias tus posibilidades de recibir respuesta al menos un 90%.

Comment: Done! I hope it's good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ActionListener`, you are calling

```
painelPrincipal.repaint();
```

before you add the new panel `painelAluno`. This should happen after it has been added *and* the panel has been revalidated:

```
painelPrincipal.add(painelAluno, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
painelPrincipal.revalidate();
painelPrincipal.repaint();
```

Aside from this `painelPrincipal.setSize(...)` has no effect as you're using a layout manager. The above snippet should suffice.